# Failed to save settings . Please restart IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1 linux pc

Tags: linux, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1 in my linux pc and I have a problem with the auto-saving.  When I close IntelliJ and reopen my IDE, it doesn't save my configuration and shows me this message:

Unable to save settings : Failed to save settings . Please restart IntelliJ IDEA

what should I do for this.

Comment: Can you show the full error - see it the idea.log file (Help | Show Log in ... action).

Answer (score 4):

Check the full error in idea.log file (Help | Show Log in ... action). Usually it contains the reason.

It may help to re-open the project using File | New | Project from Existing Sources and select to delete existing [project configuration files](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-projects.html#file-based).

Comment: You mean `.idea` directory? I've removed it and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

After about 10+ hours of searching the web, I found that when you sign out from your Google account logged in to Android Studio, the errors are gone.